# Meaning of stripping Satan of his legs and walking on his belly

Tags: parashat-bereishit, curse, evil-inclination, satan

*This question deals exclusively with the metaphorical interpretation of the Serpent as Satan/evil inclination/Devil/etc, not as a biological species*.

The Serpent was cursed by God with :

> "וַיֹּאמֶר ה"א אֶל־הַנָּחָשׁ כִּי עָשִׂיתָ זֹּאת
> אָרוּר אַתָּה מִכָּל־הַבְּהֵמָה וּמִכֹּל חַיַּת הַשָּׂדֶה
> עַל־גְּחֹנְךָ תֵלֵךְ וְעָפָר תֹּאכַל כָּל־יְמֵי חַיֶּיךָ׃"
> "Then God said to the serpent, “Because you did this,
> more cursed shall you be than all cattle and all the wild beasts:
> On your belly shall you crawl, and dirt shall you eat all the days of your life." [Gen 3.14](http://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.3.14?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en)

The commentators I looked at unanimously interpret "נחש" *here* as a species, completely ignoring the idea of it being a metaphorical evil being .

For the metaphorical נחש, what does the curse mean?

Comment: You may want to read from the introduction the Guide for the Perplexed, [about the two kinds of _Meshalim_](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Guide_for_the_Perplexed%2C_Introduction%2C_Prefatory_Remarks.11-14?lang=bi&lang2=he). It could be the [metaphorical] story with the serpent would fit the second category (at least according to Maimonides).

Comment: @TamirEvan Yes, this is exactly my point, you have to explain all phenomena with that hypothesis. You can't use the metaphorical hypothesis for some versions and the literal animal hypothesis for others.

Comment: Actually, in the second type of _Mashal_ I alluded to, only some elements of the _Mashal_ have a _Nimshal_. So, if a commentator feels that a part of the _Mashal_, that doesn't have a corresponding _Nimshal_, needs interpretation, he interprets it - literally (in the context of the _Mashal_). Those that have a _Nimshal_, he interprets metaphorically (in the context of the _Nimshal_). At least according to the Guide, it's not an either-or situation - it can be both.